# C# Fetch certain email with subject

Tags: c#, windows, email, hotmail

How can I fetch an email, that has the subject I'm looking for in Hotmail using C#.

e.g. I want the emails(body/message) that has the word "Yahoo" in its subject.

Tried using many examples online but they weren't really clear. Thanks

Comment: You need to post some code or narrow down your question. Your question as it stands now is either "can someone write the code for me" or "can someone suggest a library for me", both of which are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to your hotmail account using the OpenPop.Net open source library. It has a lot of useful methods to communicate with a POP3 server. There is a lot of useful examples online. A simple code to connect to the POP3 server could work look this:

```
using(Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect(hotmailHostName, pop3Port, useSsl);
    client.Authenticate(username, password, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

    // And here you can use the client.GetMessage() method to get a desired message. 
    // You can iterate all the messages and check properties on each of them. 
}
```

The hotmailHostName should be "pop3.live.com". 
The pop3Port should be 995. 
The useSsl should be true.